# Prove $V_{j,kl}-V_{j,kl}=R^i_{jkl} V_i$

Tags: differential-geometry

I am given the Riemann curvature tensor of the first kind $$R^i _{jkl}=\frac{\partial \Gamma ^i _{jl}}{\partial x^k}-\frac{\partial \Gamma^i _{jk}}{\partial x^l}+\Gamma^r _{jl} \Gamma^i _{rk}-\Gamma^r _{jk}\Gamma^i _{rl}$$

Where $\Gamma$ denotes Christoffel symbols.

Given a covariant vector field $(V_i)$,I am trying to prove that covariant differentiation of a second order leads to the curvature tensor described by the identity $$V_{j,kl} -V_{j,lk}=R^i _{jkl} V_i$$

This is the proof.

By definition $V_{i,jk}=(V_{i,j),k}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k} V_{i,j}- \Gamma ^r _{ik} V_{r,j}-\Gamma^r_{jk} V_{i,k}$

And we substitute in $$V_{i,j}=\frac{\partial V_i}{\partial x^j}-\Gamma ^s _{ij} V_s$$

Then we get $$V_{i,jk}=\frac{\partial^2 {V_i}}{\partial x^k \partial x^j}-\frac{\partial \Gamma^s_{ij}}{\partial x^k}V_s -\Gamma ^s _{ij}
 \frac{\partial V_s}{\partial x^k}-\Gamma^r_{ik} \frac{\partial V_r}{\partial x^j} + \Gamma ^r _{ik}\Gamma^s _{rj} V_s -\Gamma^r _{jk} \frac{\partial V_i}{\partial x^r} +\Gamma^r _{jk} \Gamma^s _{ir} V_s$$

and $$V_{i,kj}=\frac{\partial^2 {V_i}}{\partial x^j \partial x^k}-\frac{\partial \Gamma^s_{ik}}{\partial x^j}V_s -\Gamma ^s _{ik} \frac{\partial V_s}{\partial x^k}-\Gamma^r_{ij} \frac{\partial V_r}{\partial x^k} + \Gamma ^r _{ij}\Gamma^s _{rk} V_s -\Gamma^r _{kj} \frac{\partial V_i}{\partial x^r} +\Gamma^r _{kj} \Gamma^s _{ir} V_s$$

> Where do I go from here?
>
> Does $\Gamma^r _{kj}=$\Gamma^r_{jk}$?

I tried to subtract the two but I could not get the required answer.

Comment: At a glance it looks like you get the right answer, at least up to signs. Keep in mind that $r, s$ are dummy indices and can be freely interchanged, and that $\Gamma_{ij}^s$ is symmetric in $i, j$.

Comment: @Travis If I do the subtractions, it doesn't work out

Answer (score 1):

To rephrase the question slightly, prove:

\begin{equation}V_{i,jk}-V_{i,kj}=R^i_{jkl} V_i\end{equation}

Since 
\begin{equation}V_{i,jk}\equiv (V_{i,j}),_k\equiv {\partial \over \partial x^k}
(V_{i,j})-\Gamma^r_{ik}(V_{r,j})-\Gamma^r_{jk}(V_{i,r})\end{equation}

Substitute 
 \begin{equation}V_{i,j}={\partial V_i \over \partial x^j}-\Gamma^s_{ij}V_s\end{equation}

Then,
\begin{equation}V_{i,jk}={\partial ^2V_i \over {\partial x^k \partial x^j}} - {\partial \Gamma^s_{ij} \over \partial x^k}V_s - \Gamma^s_{ij}{\partial V_s \over \partial x^k} - \Gamma^r_{ik}{\partial V_r \over \partial x^j}+\Gamma^r_{ik}\Gamma^s_{rj}V_s - \Gamma^r_{jk} {\partial V_i \over \partial x^r}+\Gamma^r_{jk}\Gamma^s_{ir}V_s\end{equation}

Interchanging j and k gives,
\begin{equation}V_{i,kj}={\partial ^2V_i \over {\partial x^j \partial x^k}} - {\partial \Gamma^s_{ik} \over \partial x^j}V_s - \Gamma^s_{ik}{\partial V_s \over \partial x^j} - \Gamma^r_{ij}{\partial V_r \over \partial x^k}+\Gamma^r_{ij}\Gamma^s_{rk}V_s - \Gamma^r_{kj} {\partial V_i \over \partial x^r}+\Gamma^r_{kj}\Gamma^s_{ir}V_s\end{equation}

Next, the term $$\Gamma^s_{ij}{\partial V_s \over \partial x^j}$$ can be relabeled as $$\Gamma^r_{ij}{\partial V_r \over \partial x^j}$$and $$\Gamma^r_{jk} = \Gamma^r_{kj}$$and $${\partial V_i \over {\partial x^k \partial x^j}} = {\partial V_i \over {\partial x^j \partial x^k}}$$So, performing the subtraction of equation (1), in equation (5) terms 1, 4, 3, 6 and 7 cancel with terms 1, 3, 4, 6 and 7 in  (4), leaving

$$V_{i,jk}-V_{i,kj}=-{\partial \Gamma^s_{ij} \over \partial x^k}V_s + \Gamma^r_{ik}\Gamma^s_{rj}V_s + {\partial \Gamma^s_{ik} \over \partial x^j}V_s - \Gamma^r_{ij}\Gamma^s_{rk}V_s$$

$$V_{i,jk}-V_{i,kj}=(-{\partial \Gamma^s_{ij} \over \partial x^k} + \Gamma^r_{ik}\Gamma^s_{rj} + {\partial \Gamma^s_{ik} \over \partial x^j} - \Gamma^r_{ij}\Gamma^s_{rk})V_s$$

The quantity in parentheses is the Riemann tensor $$R^s_{ijk}$$so

$$V_{i,jk}-V_{i,kj} = R^s_{ijk}V_s$$